# Почему функция с параметром при вызове возвращает defined а без нее undefind?

Tags: javascript

Почему когда я вызываю функции в консоли openWindow(el); и createWindow(data, id); возвращает defined а когда вызываю без параметров то он `Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined(…)`

```
var mTitle = $('.info-project__name'),
    mslider = $('.slider-image'),
    // В data есть объекты на каждый ID
    // Если есть ID которого нет в списке data - используем свойство notFound
    storage = JSON.parse(`{
        "data": {
            "id1": {
            "title": "Детокс:",
            "content": " Применяется для  комплексного очищения организма в целом,  “Домашний Детокс” "
            },

            "id2": {
            "title": "Мужское здоровье",
            "content": "&#8220;Мужское здоровье&#8221 - сками "
            },

            "id3": {
            "title": "Женское здоровье",
            "content": "&#8220;Женское здоровье&#8221 - ",
            "img": "..../img/200x200.jpg"
            },

            "notFound": {
            "title": "Not found",
            "content": "404"
            }
        }
    }`);
// Определяется нужный заголовок/контент из JSON и отдаётся на рендер в createWindow
function openWindow(el){
  var id = el.dataset.winId,
      data = storage.data["id" + id];

  if(!data)
    data = storage.notFound;

  createWindow(data, id);
}

// Устанавливаем данные в виде (в DOM) и отображаем окно
function createWindow(data, id){
  mTitle.innerHTML =  data.title;
  mslider.innerHTML = data.img;
}
```

Comment: это не _они_ `undefined` - это они возвращают значение `undefined`

Comment: после редактирования - вопрос стал непонятен

Comment: @Grundy опечатка вышла, сейчас грамотно переформулирую

Comment: как можно вызывать функцию без параметров, если ее вызов без параметров не реализован внутри нее же?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Можно пример как должно быть правильно?

Comment: в вашем случае вызов без параметров бессмыслен. Вызывайте с параметрами.

Comment: Стоп, Вы вызываете функцию без параметров, хотя она их требует, и потом удивляетесь ошибке?

Comment: _а когда вызываю без параметров то он Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined(…)_ - а какой ожидался результат?

Comment: @Grundy Выполнение функции, взятие данных из джсон и вставка их в html

Comment: а какое значение параметра `el` ожидалось без его передачи при вызове функции?